# AWS Codeploy unauthorized when connecting to a Github organization repo

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, github-api, aws-code-deploy

Recently, I've started experiencing failures in my deployments in CodeDeploy. This problem is always happening at the Download Bundle phase, which is logging the following error:

> Error CodeUnknownError
>
> Script Name
>
> MessageCould not download bundle at
>   'https://api.github.com/repos/org_name/repo_name/tarball/commit' after
>   3 retries. Server returned codes: 401 'Unauthorized'; 401
>   'Unauthorized'; 401 'Unauthorized'; 401 'Unauthorized'.
>
> Log Tail

I already authorized CodeDeploy access for my organization.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the private token that Github created and provided to CodeDeploy? Can you confirm that if you use that token you can download from GitHub yourself?

Thanks
-Asaf